# Controllability of general nonlinear systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system

Are there any results on controllability of general non-linear systems (not necessarily affine)?:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=f(x,u)\\
y&=h(x)
\end{align}
I would like to get references on that.

Comment: Proofread? What is $y$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, $y$ is the output of the system ($x$ is state and $u$ is input).

Comment: @TedShifrin, used the tag "differential geometry", because for the specific case of nonlinear affine systems (when $f(x,u)=f_0(x)+g(x)u$) tools from differential geometry such as Lie derivative and brackets are used to provide a controllability test.

Comment: I believe you will want to see the work by Sussman and Jurdjevic, *Controllability of Nonlinear Systems*, unless I'm missing something... To be fair, $F$ is assumed analytic in that work but I do not think you can run away from that.